# I can't find this part of tool 3.0

Tags: rendering

I was making blender and I use the mouse to left-click the blender window. Then lost mine took bar.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click the little arrow (left of the word "hat.001 in your image) underlined in red in the picture below (your mouse cursor will turn into a double ended arrow when over it):

[image: Slide]